# How to run a simple HelloWorld program on jailbreak iphone ?

Tags: iphone, jailbreak, mach-o

I created a HelloWorld program, and compile it to a mach-o file. Then, I uploaded it to my jailbreak iphone via SSH.

I login with root account. Then, I tried to execute this program by running ./HelloWorld 
However, I received a "Permission denied"

My HelloWorld program is very simple:
    #include

```
int main()
{
    printf("Hello World");
    return 0;
}
```

any help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the program executable. There is a tutorial http://www.ipodstudios.com/how-to-chmod on how to do this for the ipod. I imagine this would also work for the iphone.

Comment: I set it as executable. chmod +x HelloWorld. And received another message: Bad CPU type in executable.

Comment: That means that you have not compiled your code for the proper platform. You will need to go back and look through the documentation about the iphone and how to compile for that specific target.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need a cross compiler for the iPhone in order to be able compile it on your Mac and run it on the iPhone. I believe there is a tool chain for that. Alternatively, use Theos if you are interested in jailbreak development.